# Google colab notebook - Model Maker library Custom object detection - EfficientDet architectur- Tensorflow - How to plot loss graph after training

Tags: tensorflow, matplotlib, object-detection, transfer-learning, precision-recall

I am trying to plot graphs in order to present model. I am using Tensorflow, colab notebook, EfficientDet architecture, model maker library , custom object detection using transfer learning, Pascal voc format COCO dataset. I have trained my model and got values for training loss and validation loss for ephocs=28 and batch size=5 , however I am struggling with plotting a graph. I have used the history function, model.fit, log info, tried tensorboard. Anyone have an idea how I can plot my results.

I tried to find my tmp file as colab notebook automatically saves it, however I had so many files with tmp i tried one and it didnt work, any history, log_info, model.fit function I use is not supported by the model maker library, when I use tensorboard it said there was no files , the only thing it did was show me a graph. Is there away for me to train the model and save it in a custom file? Or any other way for me to plot the graph. I can not try too many times as when the runtime disconnects I have to train the model from scratch and I am worried it will overfit or memorise the data.

I am using this code to train the model;
model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=5, train_whole_model=True, epochs=28, validation_data=val_data)

With a training and validation dataset

train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc('fire4/training','fire4/training', label_map=['fire_exit'])

val_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc('fire4/validation', 'fire4/validation', label_map=['fire_exit'])

The rest of the code is installing tflite-model-maker . importing numpy, os and tensorflow.
Unzipping my zipped file downloaded on google drive
and evaluating the validation data

Comment: Hi @Kubra Akgun, Could you please share minimal reproducible code to understand the issue. Also have a look at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification#create_a_plot_of_accuracy_and_loss_over_time) to plot the model metrics which might be helpful.